# Snowflake Grouping by Numbers

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a database and I am wanting to produce something similar to the below:

| Dollar Amount | Count |
| --- | --- |
| $ 0 - $500 | 3 |
| $501 - $1999 | 10 |
| $2000 - $2999 | 23 |

What is the easiest way to get something similar to that? I have a list of purchase IDs and dollar amount of purchase. My thought was using cases when purchase between those amounts but the count of IDs isn't working as expected.

Comment: Which bucket would a number like $500.5 fall into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather simple method is to use a CASE statement, the rules are evaluated in order, so you just need to check increasing cutout values.

```
with data as (
select * from values
    (1),(2),(499),
    (501),(1000),(1499),
    (2014)
)
select 
    case 
        when column1 <= 500 then '$ 0 - $500'
        when column1 <= 1999 then '$501 - $1999'
        when column1 <= 2999 then '$$2000 - $2999'
    end as "Dollar Amount"
    ,count(*) as "Count"
from data
group by 1;
```

gives:

| Dollar Amount | Count |
| --- | --- |
| $ 0 - $500 | 3 |
| $501 - $1999 | 3 |
| $$2000 - $2999 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

We can start by defining an array of arbitrary buckets, and then looking for rows that fit within:

```sql
with buckets as (
    select value, lead(value) over(order by value) next_value
    from table(flatten([0,500,1000,2000]))
    qualify next_value is not null
)

select value||'-'||next_value range, count_if(c_acctbal>=value and c_acctbal<next_value) c
from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.customer
join buckets
group by 1
order by any_value(value);
```

[image]

Comment: `from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.customer
join buckets group by 1`  - `cross join`/cartesian in plain sight :)

Comment: I could move the `count_if(c_acctbal>=value and c_acctbal<next_value)` to the `join on ()` -- indeed

Comment: That too :) My main intention was to emphasize that you have chosen the most interesting way to write cross join available   1)  `FROM t1 CROSS JOIN t2` 2) `FROM t1, t2` 3) `FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON TRUE` 4) `FROM t1 JOIN t2`